# How to create a custom shape in JointJs, which consists out of 2 or more basic shapes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, jointjs

I want to create a shape in Joint JS.

Which I could initialize and lets say have rectangle and circle as one shape.

As far as I know, only path method is something near.

Answer (score 5):

I have just come to an answer. I needed to extend the joint.dia.Element class. Here is how the code looks, which draws a rectangle with two circles(extension):

```
joint.shapes.basic.myShape = joint.dia.Element.extend({

            markup: '<g class="rotatable"><g class="scalable"><rect class="outer"/><circle class="inner"/><circle class="inner1"/></g></g>',
            defaults: joint.util.deepSupplement({
                type: "basic",
                size: {
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20
                },
                attrs: {
                    ".outer": {
                        stroke: 'black',
                        'fill-opacity': 1,
                        width: 10,
                        height: 15
                    },
                    ".inner": {
                        transform: "translate(10, 10)",
                        r: 8,
                        fill: "#000000"
                    },
                    ".inner1": {
                        transform: "translate(10, 10)",
                        r: 6,
                        fill: "#fff"
                    }
                }
            }, joint.dia.Element.prototype.defaults)
});
```

initializing (to stencil, but directly to graph is possible too by using,
graph.addCell):

```
 var r1 = new joint.shapes.basic.myShape({
            size: {
                width: 60,
                height: 60
            }
        });

 stencilData.load([r1], 'basic');
```

Comment: Andrius, how do you create stencilData?

Comment: These lines of code are very clearly given in the Documentation   `graph = new joint.dia.Graph
    var paper = new joint.dia.Paper({
        el: $('#paper1'),
        width: 1000,
        height: 1000,
        gridSize: 1,
        model: graph
    });`

  var stencilData = new joint.ui.Stencil({
        graph: graph,
        paper: paper,
        width: 500,
        height: 500
    });